# T-SQL NOT IN works, but NOT EXISTS does not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

As new records are added to a table, I need to mark the old records for that 'level' as old.  I can do this with a NOT IN, but NOT EXISTS does not work.  I suspect it has to do with subquery correlation as explained here:
[NOT EXISTS query doesn't work on Informix while same query with NOT IN works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936904/not-exists-query-doesnt-work-on-informix-while-same-query-with-not-in-works)
but I don't understand why & could use further explanation. Here's some example code:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT, level INT, someDate datetime, mostRecent int)
GO
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT 1, 1, '1/1/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, '2/2/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, '3/3/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, '4/4/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, '5/5/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3, '6/6/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 4, '7/7/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 5, '8/8/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 6, '9/9/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 6, '10/10/2010', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 8, '11/11/2012', 1
GO
-- this doesn't work
UPDATE t2 SET mostRecent = 0
FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM t2
    JOIN
        (SELECT level, max(someDate) as someDate FROM t2 group by level) as maxrows
    ON t2.someDate = maxrows.someDate)
GO
-- this works
UPDATE t2 SET mostRecent = 0
FROM t2
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT t2.id FROM t2
    JOIN
        (SELECT level, max(someDate) as someDate FROM t2 group by level) as maxrows
    ON t2.someDate = maxrows.someDate)
```

Comment: Looks like a flawed update to me.  If you had a SELECT 2, 1, ''4/4/2010'', 1 UNION ALL then it would find ID 4 also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong, it needs to be:

```
UPDATE T SET mostRecent = 0
FROM t2 as T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM 
     (SELECT level, max(someDate) as someDate FROM t2 group by level) as maxrows
      WHERE T.someDate = maxrows.someDate)
```

I've added alias to the tables to keep it clear

In your original query, you are not linking anything from the `NOT EXISTS` query to your `UPDATE` statement, therefore it will always return results, and it will "exist" for every record in the table to be updated.

Comment: Thank you!  I suspected the subquery wasn't correlating correctly to the update.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your whole query to this for better performance, the script from Joao should have fixed your described error:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    mostrecent, 
    row_number() over (partition by level order by somedate desc) rn
  FROM t2
)
UPDATE CTE
SET 
  mostrecent = 0
WHERE 
  mostrecent = 1
  and rn > 1
```

Comment: I agree my original approach is a little klunky; I need to get better at Common Table Expressions, and XML Path, and CLR Assemblies, and ... the list goes on.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk is there any performance advantage between using the CTE or using UPDATE ... FROM (using your table in the FROM clause)?

Comment: @JoaoLeal both methods uses updates, by using this method. I avoid a subselect within a subselect, it also have better readability and updates fewer rows. Yes it will perform faster

Comment: I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742999/performance-of-cte-vs-subquery-in-update-statement